# LINQ - Invalid Operation Exception

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Please see the code below:

```
static MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<DataObjects.Application, BusinessObjects.Application>();
        });

        public BusinessObjects.Application getApplication(string UserID)
        {
            using (CreditCardPreQualificationEntities CreditCardPreQualificationDatabase = new CreditCardPreQualificationEntities())
            {
                //DataObjects.Application application = CreditCardPreQualificationDatabase.Applications.FirstOrDefault(c => c.userID== UserID);
                BusinessObjects.Application application = CreditCardPreQualificationDatabase
                    .Applications
                    .ProjectTo<BusinessObjects.Application>(config)
                    .Where(c => c.UserID == UserID)
                    .ToList().Single();
                return application;
                //return new BusinessObjects.Application();
            }
        }
```

An invalidoperationexception is thrown because the user does not have any applications.  How can I handle this in the LINQ uqery?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `.ToList().Single();` with `.FirstOrDefault();`. Then `application` will be `null` if not found.